# Attribute Indexes ArcSDE 9.3.1 for Attribute Joins on GUID field types

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I create my joins on primary/foreign keys that are guids...I don't seem to be able to create an index on this field in my target table. After joining to this table it takes 4 minutes to open the source table.

Can indexes be built on guids fields..if not what work arounds do you guys see? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a index can be built on it; but you are indexing a long string value so that has some cost but overall you can use that to build a consistent string to join against. Just remember that a GUID by nature is always unique; so if you want to have a many-one relationship then one of your fields will need to be a string since you couldn't have many rows with the same GUID.

Comment: When running the create index tool in ArcMap, that field does not show up as an option.

Comment: You need to add it to the layer from ArcCatalog; That should allow you to add it. Not being able to do it from inside ArcMap I think has to do with locking and the schema change.